# game crash on android phone while using unity UI

Tags: unity, gui

I am trying to use an unity UI in my game. Initially I Created Canvas with all settings what I need then I compiled it on my phone its working perfectly. Inside the Canvas if I created any button or image means in editor its working fine but in android mobile the game get crash. I don't know what's happening?

Note: I already create the game with simple ui system. in that ui using box collider and listenerClicks() I handling all functions. Now i am trying to convert this system to Unity UI system.

[Here my Logcat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d4ithukwnpt7yk/log.txt?dl=0)

I am using Unity 5.2, c#

Comment: Did you check the logcat?

Comment: No. I don't know about that

Comment: @HamzaHasan i collected the logcat as a text file what should I do now?

Comment: @HamzaHasan I read "Did you check the lolcat?"

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt is there is any link to upload my logcat here?

Comment: If it's a text file, you can edit your question and put it in a code bloc.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt i attached my logcat PFA

Comment: @ManojBalajiM For future reference, when uploading text, using an external site and a link in your question is discouraged. Links might get broken, making your question not helpful for future readers, and also people can't find your question when googling the error that might appear in your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a problem in unity version. after update my unity the problem got fixed.

other case if we click reimport all options it may fix.